# jQuery plugin using only last element's values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I built a plugin that's supposed to transform any button into a modal style form, given a url where the form can be fetched.

It works fine with only one element, but when the selector returns multiple elements, all buttons use the last element's data when the get & post methods are called inside the plugin.

I've tried several answered question in SO, but haven't been able to locate and fix the bug. Looks like I'm missing something.

Here's the complete code. You'll see some `{% django tags %}` and `{{ django context variables }}` but just ignore them.

Thanks!

A.

EDIT: typo; EDIT2: added html; EDIT3: removed django tags and context vars.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-1234" data-uuid="1234">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="title-1234">Title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="body-1234">Body</div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="cancel-1234">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="confirm-1234">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
    // define the modalform class
    function ModalForm($button){
        /*
        You can use ModalForm to automate the ajax-form-modal process with TB3.

        Usage:

        var mf = new ModaForm($('#my-button'));  // that's it
        */
        self = this;
        self.$button = $button;
        self.$modal = $('#modal-1234');
        // get vars
        self.target = self.$button.attr('data-target');
        self.uuid = self.$modal.attr('data-uuid');
        self.$modal_title = $('#title-' + self.uuid);
        self.$modal_body = $('#body-' + self.uuid);
        self.$modal_confirm = $('#confirm-' + self.uuid);
        self.modal_confirm_original_text = self.$modal_confirm.html()
        self.$modal_cancel = $('#cancel-' + self.uuid);
        self.$alerts = $('[data-exsutils=push-alerts]').first();
        self.$spinner = $('<p class="center"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-spinner fa-spin orange bigger-300"></i></p>');
        // bind button click to _get
        self.$button.on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            self._get();
        });
    }

    ModalForm.prototype._get = function(){
        /*
        Issue a get request to fetch form and either render form or push alert when complete.
        */
        var self = this;
        // show modal, push spinner and change title
        self.$modal.modal('show');
        self.$modal_body.html(self.$spinner);
        self.title = typeof(
            self.$button.attr('data-title')) !== 'undefined' ? 
            self.$button.attr('data-title') : 'Modal form';
        self.$modal_title.html(self.title);
        // get content
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: self.target,
            statusCode: {
                403: function(data){
                    // close modal
                    // forbidden => close modal & push alert
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        self.$modal.modal('hide');
                        self.$alerts.html(data.responseText);
                    }, 500);
                },
                200: function(data){
                    // success => push form
                    // note that we will assign self.$form
                    var $response = $(data);
                    self.$form = $response.filter('form').first();
                    self.$modal_body.html($response);
                    self.$modal_confirm.click(function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        self._submit(self.$form);
                    });
                }
            },
            error: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }

    ModalForm.prototype._submit = function(){
        /*
        Post this.$form data and rerender form or push alert when complete.
        */
        var self = this;
        // change submit button to loading state
        self.$modal_confirm.addClass('disabled').html('Loading...');
        // issue pot request
        // cleanup
        // rebind if rerender or push alerts
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: self.$form.attr('action'),
            data: self.$form.serialize(),
            statusCode: {
                200: function(data){
                    // this is a form error
                    // so we must rerender and rebind form
                    // else we need to rerender and rebind
                    self.$form.remove();
                    var $response = $(data);
                    self.$form = $response.filter('form').first();
                    self.$modal_body.html($response);
                    self.$modal_confirm.on('click', function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        self._submit(self.$form);
                    });
                },
                201: function(data){
                    // this means object was created
                    // so we must push an alert and clean up
                    self.$form.remove();
                    delete self.$form;
                    self.$modal.modal('hide');
                    self.$modal_body.html('');
                    // we will push alerts only if there is no 201 callback
                    var callback_201 = self.$button.attr('data-callback-201');
                    if (typeof(window[callback_201]) !== 'undefined') {
                        window[callback_201](data);
                    } else {
                        self.$alerts.prepend(data);
                    };
                },
                403: function(data){
                    // this means request was forbidden => clean up and push alert
                    self.$form.remove();
                    delete self.$form;
                    self.$modal.modal('hide');
                    self.$modal_body.html('');
                    self.$alerts.prepend(data.responseText);
                }
            },
            complete: function(){
                // reset button
                self.$modal_confirm.removeClass('disabled').html(
                    self.modal_confirm_original_text);
            }
        });
    }
    window.ModalForm = ModalForm;

    // define plugin
    $.fn.modalForm = function(){
        var self = this;
        return self.each(function(){
            var el = this;
            var _ = new window.ModalForm($(el));
            $.data(el, 'modalform', _);
        });
    }

    // run plugin
    $('[data-exsutils=modal-form]').modalForm();
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Edit by @Daniel Arant:

A jsFiddle with a simplified, working version of the plugin code can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/o5j8Lq0z/13/)

Note by me: Please read the selected answer. This jsfiddle + adding `var self = this` will give you a complete picture of the problem and a good way around it.

Comment: What does your HTML look like? And out of curiosity, why are you setting window.ModalForm to equal ModalForm?

Comment: Hi, added HTML. About the window.ModalForm, the reason is debugging in other context, as in `console.log(window.ModalForm)`.

Comment: I have absolutely no experience with django so forgive me if this is a stupid question, but why are you using django tags in the JavaScript code? In particular, I'm looking at the line that reads `self.uuid = self.$modal = $('#modal-{{ uuid }}');`.

Comment: Hi Daniel, don't worry it's not stupid. I'm using django tags because that way I can make javascript dynamic according to other backend processes. For instance, I may want to translate text or generate a new and independent modal, as in this case.

Comment: Gotcha. I guess I'm primarily looking at the line that reads `self.uuid = self.$modal = $('#modal-{{ uuid }}');`. I assume you are using that HTML as a template for the modal, in which case you could give it a generic ID and re-assign the id to whatever you like in the ModalForm constructor.

At this point I'm just trying to get a working example up and running in jsFiddle so I can step through it.

Comment: Exactly, I'd be great if you get a JSFiddle up and running. I'm not that experienced with JS and always run into these kind of bugs. Thanks.

Comment: To get a working jsFiddle, you'll need to just temporarily supply concrete values where the django tags currently are, and also provide a some html and JavaScript demonstrating the usage of the plugin.

Comment: Replaced tags and context variables with static values.

Comment: Is this making use of a jquery UI widget or some other kind of JavaScript modal widget at `self.$modal.modal('show')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of your problem is the line `self = this` in the `ModalForm` constructor. Since you did not use the keyword `var` before `self`, the JavaScripts interpreter thinks that `self` is a property of the global `window` object and declares it as such. Therefore, each time the `ModalForm` constructor is invoked, self takes on a new value, and all of the references to `self` in the event handlers created by the constructor for previous buttons then point to the new, most recent instance of `ModalForm` which has been assigned to the global `self` property.

In order to fix this particular problem, simply add the keyword `var` before `self = this`. This makes self a local variable rather than a global one, and the click event callback functions will point to their very own instance of ModalForm instead of the last instance that was assigned to `self`.

I created a working jsFiddle based on your code, which can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/o5j8Lq0z/13/)

I stripped down the plugin code to eliminate the ajax calls for the sake of simplicity. I also eliminated all of the uuid references. Once you get a reference to the modal as a jQuery object, you can use jQuery's `.find()` method to obtain references to the various components of the modal.

If you have any questions about my quick and dirty revision of your plugin

Comment: Yes! I noticed and was about to write the answer. I was playing around with the JSFiddle and noticed this. Thanks!!